# rmarkdown readthedown template error

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I have this error when I knit the `readthedown` template. In fact, all html `rmdformats` templates for `rmarkdown` fail.

I get this error:

> "D:/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --variable "gallery:false" --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "D:\R-3.3.2\library\rmdformats\templates\readthedown\readthedown.html" --highlight-style kate --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\602891\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2RnypK\rmarkdown-str26c4151511b5.html" 
>       pandoc.exe: Could not fetch /tabsets.js
>       /tabsets.js: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
>       Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: MathJax doesn't work with self_contained when not using the rmarkdown "default" template. 
>       2: running command '"D:/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.
>
> md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --variable "gallery:false" --standalone --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --template "D:\R-3.3.2\library\rmdformats\templates\readthedown\readthedown.html" --highlight-style kate --variable "theme:bootstrap" --include-in-header "C:\Users\602891\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2RnypK\rmarkdown-str26c4151511b5.html"' had status 67 
>       Execution halted

I thought that installing the package should work but I can't seem to knit it.

Comment: Maybe this issue: https://github.com/juba/rmdformats/issues/23 ; you should try installing the github version as juba suggests: `devtools::install_github("juba/rmdformats")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question. `rmarkdown` was misspelled in the body and the title. I refomatted the error message so that it is easier to read. I tried to correct the grammar and removed salutations which aren't required on SO. I've added the rmarkdown tag. Please, [edit] your question and explain the steps/commands which caused the error. This is required on SO to reproduce the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that has been fixed in the last development version. For now, installing from github should solve the issue:

```
devtools::install_github("juba/rmdformats")
```